# Vlookup keeps Generating Error in VBA Script

Tags: excel, vba

My Vlookup keeps failing on me with my code. Some insight would be great.  Otherwise my code works fine.

```
Sub PopulateSSPplate()

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SampleCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LIMS_Import").Range("D1000").End(xlUp).Row - 3
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim Range1 As Range

    Set Range1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Samples").Range("AK2:AL145")
    Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Samples")
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SSP Plate")

    For Y = 0 To 1
     'MsgBox (Y)
        For X = 0 To 2
        'MsgBox (X)
            For j = 1 To 6
                'MsgBox (j)
                For k = 1 To 4
                    Sheet2.Cells((3 + k), (2 + j)).Offset((6 * X), (8 * Y)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet2.Range("T3"), Range1, 2, False)
                   ' MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SSP Plate").Cells((3 + k), (2 + j)).Offset((6 * X), (9 * Y)).Value)
                    SampleCount = SampleCount - 1
                    'MsgBox (SampleCount)
                    If SampleCount = 0 Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
                'MsgBox (SampleCount)
                If SampleCount = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            'MsgBox (SampleCount)
            If SampleCount = 0 Then
                    Exit For
            End If
        Next X
        'MsgBox (SampleCount)
         If SampleCount = 0 Then
            Exit For
         End If
    Next Y

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: "...Vlookup keeps failing on me with my code" - what does that mean? Do you get an error in the formula, does VBA throw an error, does the lookup work but return an unexpected result, etc...Also, IIRC `Sheet1`/`Sheet2` can be used in VBA without creating a variable and *could* lead to confusion.  I recommend changing the variable names to, say `samplesWS`/`sspWS` instead.

Comment: Figured it out Stupid mistake no need to go any further on this one.